# Is this a Pythonic way of structuring modules?

Tags: python, module

Suppose that I was writing an application that used a number of GUI controls that I'm writing Python code for. Each control is described by a class, and I want to aggregate all of those classes into a module, called `gui`. As a seasoned C/C++ developer, it makes most sense to me to separate the class implementations by file, like this:

```
gui/MainWindow.py
gui/Widget1.py
gui/Widget2.py
```

Where, in the above, the specification of the `MainWindow` class would be in `MainWindow.py`. If I lay the files out in this way, however, then the syntax to get at those classes looks like:

```
import gui
w = gui.MainWindow.MainWindow()
```

which seems redundant. A way around this limitation is to edit `gui/__init__.py` to say:

```
from gui.MainWindow import *
from gui.Widget1 import *
from gui.Widget2 import *
```

which brings the classes into the `gui` module namespace. I can then access them as follows:

```
w = gui.MainWindow()
```

Is this typically done? Does it have sufficient Pythonicity to be considered appropriate in the community? One drawback that I can see is that I need to be sure to keep `gui/__init__.py` as I add new submodules to the `gui` module; I don't like manual steps like that.

Thoughts and/or suggestions of how to better address this would be great.

Comment: You're asking for opinions and recommendations -- that's not considered a constructive question here. Basically, other than being explicit rather than using `*` in `__init__.py`, you've already figured out the usual way.

Comment: Agreed that this butts up against the guidelines. I only thought it appropriate because there seems to be general objective consensus in the community on programming techniques that are considered Pythonic and those that aren't.

Comment: probably you mean packages instead of modules *nitpick*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't import `*` (unless you're *certain* there can't be a conflict; this rule can be bent for *package* authors), but certainly this is otherwise an acceptable solution.

Comment: Assuming I have control of the entire `gui` module, I should be able to verify that there won't be any conflicts. the `import *` only brings the symbols into the module-level namespace (unless there's something I don't see).

Comment: Additionally, setting `__all__` in each submodule can restrict it further.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have noted these PEPs and documentation sites before:

- [PEP8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- [PEP 20 -- The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)
- [Packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

So the only thing I can add to this is not to use `import *`. One example:

```
>>> from pylab import *
>>> any(False for i in range(5))
True
```

While you validly argue that you know what you are doing. You cannot assume that all of the potential re-users that `import *` from your package know what they're shadowing while they tear down the final namespace barrier between their and your code.
This gives nasty errors. See also:

> Now what happens when the user writes `from sound.effects import *`? Ideally, one would hope that this somehow goes out to the filesystem, finds which submodules are present in the package, and imports them all. This could take a long time and importing sub-modules might have unwanted side-effects that should only happen when the sub-module is explicitly imported. [Docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

and

> (import * is not an option ;-) [PEP328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)

and

> Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those! [PEP20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

But these are only guidelines/recommendations/personal preferences, and there certainly  exist edge cases when these do not apply.